# Unable to perform database migrations in asp.net core [Column NULL]

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.net core, I'm trying to update a model class to change the field from an iFormFile to a string. 
ie. In response to a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447338/adding-images-to-asp-net-core)
 to store the filename instead of the image file instead.

After updating the model class and performed the changes accordingly, the webpage prompted me to update the database / migration.

Firstly, can someone point me to information on ***what does it mean by migrations***?

Secondly, I have the following errors below after typing the commands

```
dotnet ef database update
```

I receive the following errors:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'StaffID', table 'aspnet-
newbienoob-59e13649-49be-4a5f-9365-d1b8cc6588d5.dbo.Employee'; 
column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Temi for the reply.

The database migration somehow failed.

After understanding what the up() and down() method does in the generated cs file from the migration meant. I altered the SQL statements myself.

ie.

```
public partial class initial2 : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "StaffID",
            table: "Employee");

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "StaffIdentity",
            table: "Employee",
            nullable: true,
            defaultValue: "");
    }
}
```

Basically what I did was to rollback all the migrations and rework on a new migration to update the table.

ie. `dotnet ef migrations remove`

I'm able to revert from the base table from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're creating your database using code first migrations. First of, you need to migrate your database  from the model using an IformFile datatype to the one using string datatype.

use the following syntax in command prompt.
dotnet ef migrations add [migration name] . Like so

`dotnet ef migrations add myfirstmigration`

not the best migration name, but you get the idea. 
Next you update the database like you've already done.

`dotnet ef database update`

Comment: I did that actually. I still have the problem

The error is as follows

Project newbienoob (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because Input items added from last build
Compiling newbienoob for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
Compilation succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time elapsed 00:00:02.7244932

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'StaffID', table 'aspnet-newbienoob-59e13649-49be-4a5f-9365-d1b8cc6588d5.dbo.Employee'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: It seems that there are several database migrations which failed.